# Laravel 5.2 - pluck() method returns array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-5

I'm trying to upgrade my project L5.1 -> L5.2. In [upgrade guide](http://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0) there's one thing which isn't clear for me:

> The `lists` method on the Collection, query builder and Eloquent query
>   builder objects has been renamed to `pluck`. The method signature
>   remains the same.

That's ok, rename refactoting from `lists()` to `pluck()` isn't a problem. But what with useful `pluck()` method which was in L5.0 and L5.1?

From the [5.0 documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries):

> Retrieving A Single Column From A Row
>
> ```
> $name = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'John')->pluck('name');
> ```

What is the alternative for old `pluck()` method in L5.2?

**UPDATE:**

Example:

```
var_dump(DB::table('users')->where('id', 1)->pluck('id'));
```

L5.1:

```
// int(1)
```

L5.2:

```
// array(1) { [0]=> int(1) }
```

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty confusing.  In 5.0, `pluck()` meant select 1 field from a row.  Then in 5.1, they removed `pluck()` and replaced it with `value()`.  Then in 5.2, they replace `lists()`, which returns the whole column, with `pluck()`.  So if you've been around since 4.2, you might get confused :/

Answer (score 129, accepted):

The current alternative for `pluck()` is `value()`.

Comment: Thank you! This absolutely should be in the upgrade guide as it's breaking change.

Comment: I see that it is in upgrade guide for 5.1: http://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.1.0 My bad I didn't catch this change in prev release.

Comment: There is actually notice about this change: "The Eloquent collection instance now returns a base Collection (`Illuminate\Support\Collection`) for the following methods: `pluck`, ..."

Comment: It is much easier to use value as it is in ready non array form.. especially in toggle type operations

Comment: can someone please explain the reasoning behind such naming? why not "column"?

Answer (score 23):

> In Laravel 5.1+, you can use the value() instead of pluck.

To get first occurence, You can either use

```
DB::table('users')->value('name');
```

or use,

```
DB::table('users')->where('id', 1)->pluck('name')->first();
```

Answer (score 22):

laravel pluck returns an array

if your query is:

```
 $name = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'John')->pluck('name');
```

then the array is like this (key is the index of the item. auto incremented value):

```
[
    1 => "name1",
    2 => "name2",
    .
    .
    .
    100 => "name100"
]
```

but if you do like this:

```
$name = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'John')->pluck('name','id');
```

then the key is actual index in the database.

```
key||value
[
    1 => "name1",
    2 => "name2",
    .
    .
    .
    100 => "name100"
]
```

you can set any value as key.

Answer (score 14):

I use laravel 7.x and I used this as a workaround:`->get()->pluck('id')->toArray();`

it gives back an array of ids `[50,2,3]` and this is the whole query I used:

```
   $article_tags = DB::table('tags')
    ->join('taggables', function ($join) use ($id) {
        $join->on('tags.id', '=', 'taggables.tag_id');
        $join->where([
            ['taggable_id', '=', $id],
            ['taggable_type','=','article']
        ]);
    })->select('tags.id')->get()->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

Comment: `AModel::select('id',...)->where(...)->get()->pluck('id');` gives array of integer values of `id`, when `AModel::select('id',...)->where(...)->get()->pluck('id')->toArray();`  gives  array alike `[0=>id0, 1=>id1,...., n=>idN]`, Have tested.

Answer (score -1):

In the original example, why not use the select() method in your database query?

```
$name = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'John')->select("id");
```

This will be faster than using a PHP framework, for it'll utilize the SQL query to do the row selection for you. For ordinary collections, I don't believe this applies, but since you're using a database...

Larvel 5.3: [Specifying a Select Clause](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#selects)

Comment: need to add ->get(); you still need to use PHP to format the array

Comment: Php operations are much faster than Mysql queries.

Comment: @AnkitBalyan are you being sarcastic? mysql is MUCH faster than php. Try processing a million rows in each...