# How can i parse the query builder result?

Tags: php, laravel, parsing, foreach, query-builder

I use query builder for select data from DB. My query builder is :

```
    $end_date = DB::table('synon_library_lending')
    ->where('end_date', '<', Carbon::today())
    ->pluck('end_date', 'id');
```

and the result of this query is:
{"4":"2019-07-03","5":"2019-07-04"}
My problem is: i can't parse the above statement in php?
What's your solution for this problem?

Comment: https://stillat.com/blog/2018/04/11/laravel-5-retrieving-nested-array-values-with-pluck

Comment: How are  you trying to "parse" it  currently? Also, what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34405138/laravel-5-2-pluck-method-returns-array

Comment: What do you mean by `parse`? What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: What are you trying to parse?

Comment: First thank you for intercommunity. I found a solution for my problem.

Comment: Please share your solution with the community. Someone sometime might encounter this same problem.

Answer (score 0):

For show result of query builder use foreach like this code:

```
 $lists = User::orderBy('first_name')
        ->orderBy('last_name')->get();
    if ($lists->count()) {
        foreach ($lists as $item) {
            $list[$item->id] = "$item->first_name $item->last_name";
        }
    }
```